# Customising the subs() functionality of Function subclasses in sympy

Tags: python, function, math, sympy, symbolic-math

I want to define a class of functions that follow this mathematical definition:

**Definition**
Given a function q(t) and two values, a and b, we define as variation the following function

```
         /
         | q(t) if s=0 or t=a or t=b
v(t,s) = |
         | v(t,s) else
         \
```

I'm trying to emulate this behaviour definition with a `Function` subclass:

```
from sympy import Function
class Variation(Function):
    # Initialize the function with the desired properties
    def __init__(self, path, st, en, name='\\vartheta'):
        self.path = path
        self.st = st
        self.en= en
        self.ends = [self.st, self.en]
        self.name = name

    # here I define the behaviour when called
    def __call__(self, tt, ss):
        if tt in self.ends:
            return self.path(tt)
        elif ss == 0:
            return self.path(tt)
        else:
            return Function(self.name)(tt,ss)  # This is the part that fails to behave
```

The function behaves well when called:

```
from sympy import *
s,t,a,b = symbols('s t a b')
c = Function('c')

Var = Variation(c, a, b)
Var(t,s), Var(a,s), Var(t,0) 

> \vartheta(t,s), q(a), q(t)
```

but as expected, if we do:

```
Var(t,s).subs(t,0)

> \vartheta(t,0)
```

Is there a way to modify the `.subs()`'s method behaviour? Because as far as I am aware, the `integrate()` function makes use of `subs()`.

I also tried changing `Function(self.name)(tt,ss)` to `self(tt,ss)` but this gave me an infinite loop (also expected).

On the same note, is there a good guide to construct arbitrary mathematical functions on python?

**Edit**: Tried

```
def Var(t,s):
    return Piecewise((c(t), s==0), (c(t), t==a), (c(t), t==b), (Function('v')(t,s), True ))

Var(t,s).subs(t,0)
```

but it had the same problems.

Comment: maybe [sympy-functions-elementary-piecewise](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#sympy-functions-elementary-piecewise) would be useful?

Comment: @f5r5e5d, tried that, but it has the same problems

Comment: @AngelJoaniquetTukiainen If you only want to integrate `v(t,s)`, you may as well use `v(t,s)` for all values of `t`, `s` since the set of values of `t` and `s` for which it becomes `q(t)` is of measure zero.

Comment: @Stelios The Idea is to implement variational derivates, and learn how to make mathematical definitions with sympy. I'm starting to realize that it might be more dificoult than anticipated (the second part, for the first one is possible to do work arounds)

Comment: @Stelios and in calculus of variations just those measure zero parts are the ones that we are interested on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to reshape how you go about this a bit.

#### Creating your `Var` function.

You really want `Var` in your example to be a `Function` class. `sympy` is designed around functions being classes and using the `eval()` class method to evaluate them. Overriding `__call__` of a `Function` subclass seems to be very non-standard and I haven't seen any `sympy` built-in functions that use that, so I don't think that's the right approach. One way of doing this would be to create a factory function to create the class for you:

```
def Variation(path_, st_, en_, v_):

    class Variation(Function):

        nargs = 2

        path = path_
        st = st_
        en = en_
        ends = [st, en]
        v = v_

        @classmethod
        def eval(cls, tt, ss):
            if tt in cls.ends:
                return cls.path(tt)

            if ss == 0:
                return cls.path(tt)

            return cls.v(tt, ss)

    return Variation

Var = Variation(c, a, b, Function(r'\vartheta'))
```

- I've replaced your `'name'` variable with an actual function, which seems more sensible.

Now you can create variations and prevent immediate evaluation (if you want) using the standard flag:

```
# by default the function is immediately evaluated...
Var(a, t)
>>> c(a)
# ...but that can be overridden
Var(a, t, evaluate=False)
>>> Variation(a, t)
```

You could also approach this by flattening the `Var` function and passing `st` `en` and `path` parameters straight into `eval()`, which removes the extra layer of the factory function:

```
class Variation(Function):

    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, path, st, en, v, tt, ss):
        if tt in [st, en]:
            return path(tt)
        elif ss == 0:
            return path(tt)
        else:
            return v(tt, ss)

Variation(c, a, b, Function(r'\vartheta'), a, t)
>>> Variation(c, a, b, \vartheta, a, t)
```

Note that since you can override `.eval()` you could modify it so that it didn't automatically simplify if you wanted, and just returned a new instance of `cls`:

```
class Variation(Function):
    no_eval = True

    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, tt, ss):

        if cls.no_eval:
            return cls(tt, ss, evaluate=False)
        # etc.
```

#### Customizing `.subs()`

By default whenever you do a `subs()`, sympy will do an `eval()` as well (as per [the `.subs()` docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/core/basic.html#Basic.subs)). So by default when you do a `.subs()` with one of your special values, `.eval()` will be called and the function will be simplified.

However, you can now override `._eval_subs()` and do your own thing, if you want:

```
class Variation(Function):
    ...
    def _eval_subs(self, old, new):
        # return self to do no substitutions at all
        return self
        # return None to continue normally by next calling _subs on the arguments to this Function
        # return some other Expression to return that instead.
```

Note that anything returned by `._eval_subs()` will subsequently be `.eval()`ed as well. You can override `.eval()` as explained above if you wanted to get round that.

So I think that answers the question about how to modify the `.subs()` behaviour...

I don't quite understand what you want with:

> is there a good guide to construct arbitrary mathematical functions on python?

I think `sympy` is pretty good, and has reasonable docs and many many inbuilt examples in its codebase which are easy to crib from. Anyway asking for guides is [off-topic (see point 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on stackoverflow ;-).

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet an answer to the  problem. But as far as I understand it, the question needs some refurbishing.

Using the `Variation` class defined in the post, I have modified `c` to `q` just to be in line with the function definition provided, just to check if I am understanding correctly the problem:

```
from sympy import *
s,t,a,b = symbols('s t a b')
q = Function('q')

Var = Variation(q, a, b)
Var(t,s), Var(a,s), Var(t,0)
```

> (\vartheta(t, s), q(a), q(t))

As expected:

```
Var(t,s).subs(t,0)
```

> \vartheta(0, s)

Which is `Var(0,s)`, given that `t` is different from `a` and `b` and `s` is not zero.